# Implementation of java script in array of name

Tags: javascript

How can I implement java script to an array. Suppose I have a text box with `name=txtphone[]`.  Though I can implement it for single text box using `document.getElementByName("txtphone")`, but it's not working for txtphone array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual syntax is "`document.getElementsByName("txtphone")`" and not "`document.getElementByName("txtphone")`".

Also, in your case, you need to use "`document.getElementsByName("txtphone[]")`", and it will return an array of elements who are having the same name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: *getElementsByName* returns an [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259), which is array-like but not an array.

Comment: @RobG - Thanks a lot for pointing me that, as I didn't know about this. In my earlier days, I used it as an array only and iterated through "*for*" loop.

Comment: Yes I am using document.getElementByName("txtphone[]") but it's not working –

Comment: @user906259 - you are missing an "s", the method is getElement**s**ByName.